# The result of Bake is black

Tags: baking

I made this building, and I want to bake this. But if I bake this, the result is only black.

How can I get a good outcome?

[image]

[.Blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1to7JHeiPeeWmQfsMrRX-PcufhsdIZes3/view?usp=drive_link)

[.fbx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UeGaXkfRRAGJccGTwNU8d9FMcJB1c2Ow/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: So, you modeled a room with a bar, tables, chairs and so on. It's a single object with 356 materials! OK. Now you want to bake textures. OK. But your room object is not properly UV unwrapped. That's bad. The UV islands overlap. This, of course, will not work because the baked image parts will overwrite each other. What was your plan? Do you want to bake everything on 1 image? Or do you want to separate the parts (table, chair, room, bar, etc) and bake them to multiple image textures? For the room (walls, floor, ceiling) it might be better to keep the seamless textures that you have.